# Intel XDK - Open personalize keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard, calculator, intel-xdk

I'm new development in Intel XDK, and I have the following problem:

I have a input text (HTML) and when user click on input I want to open only keyboard number, decimals and negative. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this blog entry by Pamela Fox. She's spent a lot of time fine tuning how to write a hybrid HTML5 app: http://blog.pamelafox.org/2012/05/triggering-numeric-keyboards-with-html5.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<input type="tel"></input>
```

This will force the number dial on most/all mobile devices.